# Show Post Title on Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

each time I click on a Post link I want the Title of the Post to appear on the Header page. See screen shot [image]

As seen, I would like the 'Devotional Message' replaced by the Post Title...

HTML Code:

```
<div id="devotionpost" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Devotional Message</h1>
            <a href="#devotion" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext">Devotion</a>
        </div><!-- header-->
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="mypost"> </div>
        </div><!-- content -->
    </div><!-- page -->
```

JS Code:

```
function showPost(id) {
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var output='';
        output += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        output += data.post.content;
        $('#mypost').html(output);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showPost(id) {
$("#devotionpost h1").html("");// to empty previous title

    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var output='';
        output += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        output += data.post.content;
        $('#mypost').html(output);

$("#devotionpost h1").html(data.post.title);// by this 'Devotional Message' replaced by the Post Title..

    });
```

Comment: Brilliant this worked but with a slight issue. Each time I go back and click on another Post, while the new Post is getting ready to Load, the Title of previously accessed post still shows and only gets replaced when the new Post finally loads. How do i empty that Header bit?

Comment: Ah.. you such a smart Guy. I did that but put it in the wrong place. Thanks for you help today